# Unable to install any ubuntu version on my old computer

Tags: kernel, 10.10

I have Intel core2duo processor on a Intel G31PR motherboard, 1GB RAM  a brand new WD 1 TeraByte hard disk.

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my hard drive. But unfortunately, I am getting errors and the setup is freezing. Everytime I try to install, I'm getting a new error and sometimes I can see the kernel panic. I tried installing from CD as well as USB flash drive, but the problem still persists.

I have tried installing Ubuntu 14.04, and Ubuntu 10.10.

What are the solutions ?

Comment: which error did you get?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/471012/ubuntu-14-04-lts-fails-to-start-with-a-kernel-panic) post?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that the minimal install cd.

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

Following this summary guide

[Ubuntu Minimal Install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519838/ubuntu-minimal-install/519860#519860)

Comment: Even this is not working!!! i get errors like this (http://i.stack.imgur.com/urRtL.jpg) and sometimes the computer simply restarts. Also I am unable to enter the recovery mode; doing so also restarts the computer. Please help.